# A word for "intimate friends" without any kind of romance?

Tags: single-word-requests, interpersonal-relations

I'm looking for a word to describe that a particular situation where two people (a man and a woman) are probably the best of friends but have no romantic inclinations towards each other. They may invade each others thoughts periodically but aren't really in a relationship per se. What would be a good word to describe this?

I'm aware of "platonic" but am wondering if there is another word?

Comment: Every word for friendship has been sexualized, aside from "friendship" which is now a trope for doomed pinings. Thus, the "friendzone".

Comment: I would probably call them "besties".

Comment: I think "bromance" is occasionally used in this sense.

Comment: *Intimate friends* can have a connotation of romance, but it also has other connotations that do not involve romance. Look up the meaning of *intimate* and you will see that sexual or romantic intimacy is behind one meaning among several.

Comment: By "intimate friends without romance," do you mean "friends with benefits," or committed asexual life partners, or just, you know, best friends?

Comment: @HotLicks *Bromance* is a strong friendship between men, not a man and a woman (brother/romance).

Comment: @Mynamite - Like I said, I think it's occasionally used for a "platonic" man/woman relationship, even though the common use of the term is for a platoinc man/man relationship.

Comment: @HotLicks I have never heard it used that way, but the world is a big place :)

Comment: *Confidant* isn't exactly what the question asked for, but could be fitting for some of the cases.

Comment: It is not possible to be friends with somebody and not be in a relationship. Relationships are not exclusively romantic or sexual. For example: You and your boss (regardless of gender) are in a business relationship, as employer and employee.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I would say they are **dear friends** or **close friends**.

Comment: Close friends or best friends works well because it implies that they are close but have a relationship just like the other friends in the person's life.

Comment: These are phrases not words

Comment: The asker is looking for words to *describe* some kind of friendship. These words are “close” or “dear”, as I provided.

Answer (score 20):

[*Platonic*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic) is the usual choice to describe this.

E.g. "They look intimate but they're merely platonic friends."

[Platonic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic) at Merriam-Webster:

> pla·ton·ic adjective \plə-ˈtä-nik, plā-\
>   2 a :  relating to or based on [platonic love](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic%20love); also :  experiencing or professing platonic love
>   b :  of, relating to, or being a relationship marked by the absence of romance or sex

[Platonic love](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platonic%20love) at Merriam-Webster:

> platonic love noun, often capitalized P
>   2 :  a close relationship between two persons in which sexual desire is nonexistent or has been suppressed or sublimated

Comment: I should state "other than platonic". Platonic has a rather professional connotation to it. Like in the office place.

Comment: @PhD I don't think platonic has that connotation (not in any of my dictionaries, or my experience with the word). It seems the perfect word.

Comment: I don't think that platonic implies "intimate".   You can have a very casual platonic relationship.

Comment: I agree with @GreenAsJade here. Platonic carries a connotation that's the opposite of intimate, not just in the sexual sense where that's the whole point of the word, but also in the sense of lessening the non-sexual intimacy of the relationship.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Is this in relation to my example? If you read my example carefully, you will note that I started "They *look* intimate..." (emphasis added). The implication is that the couple in question has seeming intimacy, but in fact, they are *not* intimate; rather, their relationship is merely platonic. At no point did I imply that a platonic relationship involves (actual) intimacy. I noticed a downvote - was this because of a misapprehension of my example?

Comment: I agree that "they look intimate but they are platonic" describes the word that the OP is looking for :)    However, _platonic_ itself is not that word.   "Their friendship is platonic" does not tell you if it is intimate or not.

Comment: @GreenAsJade while some definitions of platonic do not _require_ intimacy (see my proposed edit), it does typically imply closeness (intimacy) just not physical intimacy. I cannot recall ever seeing platonic used in a situation describing a casual relationship. Despite OP's wish for another word, it is the only offering here that actually specifically excludes the sexual while embracing closeness.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a definition of platonic that includes/specifies a close relationship.   Happy to stand corrected!

Comment: well, I am not a native English speaker, but "platonic" to me has an association with "platonic love", which is quite different  from just friendship.

Comment: @JohnDonn I am not a native speaker, either. And I understand this is about English, but just want to share that the word "platonic" is also associated with "platonic love" in Chinese. Very interesting.

Answer (score 15):

First expression that comes to mind is that they are ***bosom buddies***, which [the ODO article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bosom-buddy) defines as:

> A very close or intimate friend

The relationship between bosom buddies is, despite the fact that ‘bosom’ refers to breasts, quite platonic.

If there is something a bit secretive and reclusive about their friendship, like they’re so close nobody else can really ‘get in’, you might even say that they are [***thick as thieves***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as-thick-as-thieves):

> (Of two or more people) very close or friendly

While *bosom buddies* is colloquial and informal, *thick as thieves* is crossing over into very colloquial or even slangy territory, so it might not fit your needs. There is also something a bit disapproving about *thick as thieves*, which is not the case for *bosom buddies*.

Comment: I would be interested to know the etymology of *bosom friends*. The OED doesn't give it, but it does have an example of its use from as early as 1590. I suspect it has something to do with the practice of wet nursing. Etymoline doesn't have an entry.

Comment: I always thought ***bosom buddies*** (or the more coloquial ***butt buddies***) was more of an insult: a third person looking a two friends with jealousy or malicious intent.

Comment: @JAL I can easily imagine that for _thick as thieves_, but I’ve never heard _bosom buddies_ being used in such a way.

Comment: @JAL I've always understood Bosom Buddies (as well defined above) to mean something *very* different from 'butt buddies', which caries an implication of a homosexual relationship between two men. It's often used when one doesn't exist, but the purpose is clearly to create the implication in a teasing or insulting manner.

Comment: Hmm, I learned something today.  Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 6):

Other than platonic, I would say "kindred spirits" is an apt term to describe two intimate, but not romantic friends.

Comment: kindred spirits does not exclude the possibility of romance.

Comment: Nor does it imply friendship.  I've always interpreted it as a *recognition of similarity* in origins, interests, beliefs, or values.  You could recognize a "kindred spirit" who doesn't even know you exist.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the other answers are words that would make it clear that they're not romantic friends, but don't carry the meaning that they're very good friends.

There isn't really a formal way to express this in a single word in AmE.  The two most fitting things that come to mind are both slang and relative neologisms:

***BFF***, an Internet acronym for "best friends forever", which gained widespread recognition in the US thanks to a [funny commercial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nIUcRJX9-o).

And ***besties***, a slightly older slang term that has largely been eclipsed by BFF.

Comment: I'm not sure it was the commercial, but BFF came to my mind and I'm an American of middle age.

Comment: The term "BFF" was popular way before that commercial...

Answer (score 3):

I submit that

**confidant**

may capture the sentiment most succinctly.

> con·fi·dant
>   ˈkänfəˌdant,ˈkänfəˌdänt
>   noun
>   noun: confidant; plural noun: confidants; noun: confidante; plural noun: confidantes
>   a person with whom one shares a secret or private matter, trusting them not to repeat it to others.
>   synonyms:   close friend, bosom friend, best friend

Source is Google's mysterious dictionary, however this [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/confidant) is similar.

Answer (score 2):

Buddies.

You and he were *buddies* weren't you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GjOEcoMy2fI says it all.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=chAdBLdnaRU explains how much it means.

Google defines it as "a close friend." Buddy singular.

Need I say more... need I say more...

Comment: "Need I say more?" has always been such an ironic phrase.

Comment: I think you meant iconic!

Answer (score 0):

"just good friends"

e.g.

[**Sexual politics in the 90s: Just good friends - What's love got to do with it?**](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/sexual-politics-in-the-90s-just-good-friends--whats-love-got-to-do-with-it-1262148.html), Matthew Sweet, *The Independent*, 18 May 1997

Answer (score 0):

I have used just "best friend", although the newer BFF would suffice, as a previous poster suggested.  I think either of those terms precludes much of a romantic relationship.

Comment: Some people claim to be married to their best friend, so this term does not universally preclude romance. (But "best friend" might work if it's explicitly clear that they're not married.)

Answer (score -1):

Well, if they have sex, that doesn't necessarily mean there is romance so it would be "friends with benefits" or "sex buddies" in that case.  But the first answer of "dear friends" is probably the most accurate when describing two people who don't have sex but think about one another often.  Maybe even "bestie" or "best friend" but saying platonic is redundant.

Answer (score -2):

What immediately comes to my mind is:

**unadulterated**

or — to cool it down even further — maybe something as simple as

**pure**

would suffice? Though it sounds a bit prudish now that I wrote it…

Answer (score -2):

Why not just say that they are two people with a deep friendship?

Comment: Don't ask us "why not?"; explain to us why it should be so.